# PostgreSQL: Load testing throws error - Npgsql.PostgresException: '53300: sorry, too many clients already'

Tags: c#, postgresql

i have a simple code that tries to simulate a load test for my Postgres database

```
            List<Values> values = new List<Values>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                var mythread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                    using (var conn = db.GetDatabaseConnection())
                    {
                        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT val.id, val.name FROM val.myvalue val";
                        cmd.Prepare();
                        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        try
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Values value = new Values();
                                value.Id = reader.GetInt64(0);
                                value.Name = reader.GetString(1);

                                values.Add(value);
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                            var exception = ex;
                            throw exception;
                        }
                    }
                });

                mythread.Start();
            }
```

but when I run this I get the error **Npgsql.PostgresException: '53300: sorry, too many clients already'**

Database connection class

```
public class DatabaseConnection
{
    public NpgsqlConnection GetDatabaseConnection()
    {
        var connectionstring = "User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myvaluesdb;Pooling=True;Minimum Pool Size=10;Maximum Pool Size=100;Trust Server Certificate=true;Connection Idle Lifetime=300;keepalive=10;Timeout=60";
        NpgsqlConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // try to reconnect
            connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
        }

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            Console.WriteLine("connection status = OPEN");
        else
        {
            var exception = new Exception("could not get DB connection");
            throw exception;
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

checking the max_connections shows 100

so my question is is this normal or is there something am doing wrong that needs to be corrected and if so how can i correct this

Thanks

Comment: "Load test" is pretty vague.  If you were trying to test that max_connections does what it supposed to do under load, then you have succeeded.  If you were trying to do something else, you need to tell us what that was.

Comment: my problem is that is it possible to avoid the Npgsql.PostgresException: '53300: sorry, too many clients already' exception?

Comment: Yes, either lower the number of threads, or raise the max_connections.  Which one is better depends on what you are trying to do, which remains a mystery.

Comment: thanks jjanesso if i have like over a thousand concurrent users would i need to also raise the max_connections to that amount? Is that a good idea?

Comment: @Medard no, don't forget about reading time. 100 concurrent users might just make 10 queries at the same time. If the queries are short, you could live with a single connection as the requests for connection will queue (up to `timeout` seconds)

Answer (score 2):

If the query you execute are short (i.e. take less than 60 seconds to complete), you shouldn't see this behavior.

When the maximum number of connections (max pool size) is reached and you ask for more, npgsql will wait up to `timeout` (60 seconds in your case, 15 by default) to return one. It won't establish more, but it will wait that another connection stops being used and is returned to the pool.

In you example, you launch simultaneously 200 threads. The first 100 should have no issue, then following 100 should wait that the first 100 ones return the connections to the pool and then can establish/use their connection.

So, either the query you are running are extremely long (more than 60 seconds), or you failed to close the connection when you are done. I don't see any `close` statements, so you are relying on the connection `dispose`, but this is custom code... and your custom `dispose()` must explicitly close (or dispose) the underlying connection.